# Cursor positioning in Terminal using C program

Tags: c, cursor-position

My program will open a file and print the contents in the terminal. As the file is large, the terminal goes two or more page. I'll have to slide up to the first line of the file to read from the beginning. Is it possible using C program?

```
void hfile()
{
printf("\033[2J");
printf("\033[0;0H");
FILE *ffp;
char c;

ffp=fopen("help.txt","r");
while((c=getc(ffp))!=EOF)
    printf("%c",c);

}
```

Comment: Why don't you like to use standard shell tool like 'less' for this? Just pipe program output to it using command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not via stdlib. You will have to use some third-party library like ncurses.